# Check for duplicates in a python panda data structure

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a csv file. It looks something like this;

```
name,id,
AAA,1111,
BBB,2222,
CCC,3333,
DDD,2222,
```

I would like to extract the data in `id` column and placed inside a data structure. For this, I used python panda. Here is the code for doing this;

```
import pandas as pd
csv_file = 'C:/test.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
column_items = df['id']
```

I would like to check whether there is a duplicate among the data items in the `id` column. The data items are stored in `column_items`. In this case, there is a duplicate.

I am using python 2.7 and panda library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To find out whether there are duplicate IDs in that whole column, do

```
df['id'].duplicated().any()
```

Comment: I asked a follow-up question to find out which duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35376954/find-out-which-is-the-duplicate-in-a-python-panda-data-structure