# Find out which is the duplicate in a python panda data structure

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a csv file. It looks something like this;

```
name,id,
AAA,1111,
BBB,2222,
CCC,3333,
DDD,2222,
```

I want to find out whether there is a duplicate in column `id`. If yes, find out the duplicate. In this case, the answer is `2222`.

I have the code to find out whether a duplicate exists. Here it is;

```
import pandas as pd
csv_file = 'C:/test.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
df['id'].duplicated().any()
```

The problem is how can one find out the duplicate?

I am using python 2.7 and panda.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check for duplicates in a python panda data structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35376308/check-for-duplicates-in-a-python-panda-data-structure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) (`keep` is omit, because `keep='first'` is default). Or if you need values [`tolist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tolist.html):

```
print df['id'][df.duplicated(subset=['id'])]
3    2222
Name: id, dtype: int64

print df['id'][df.duplicated(subset=['id'])].tolist()
[2222]
```

You can check [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
print df.duplicated(subset=['id'], keep='first')
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool

print df.duplicated(subset=['id'], keep='last')
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool

print df.duplicated(subset=['id'], keep=False)
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool
```

And if you need duplicated rows use subset:

```
print df[df.duplicated(subset=['id'], keep='first')]
  name    id
3  DDD  2222

print df[df.duplicated(subset=['id'], keep='last')]
  name    id
1  BBB  2222

print df[df.duplicated(subset=['id'], keep=False)]
  name    id
1  BBB  2222
3  DDD  2222
```

Use [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) for dropping:

```
print df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id'], keep='first')
  name    id
0  AAA  1111
1  BBB  2222
2  CCC  3333

print df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id'], keep='last')
  name    id
0  AAA  1111
2  CCC  3333
3  DDD  2222

print df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id'], keep=False)
  name    id
0  AAA  1111
2  CCC  3333
```